# Как работать с файлами в android проекте

Tags: java, android, файлы

Мне нужно что бы в проекте был TXT файл. Куда его засунуть и как его достать через код java

Comment: В `assets` папку можно. Но он будет только для чтения.

Comment: поэксперементируйте с выводом в лог, хотя бы. Есть папка вашего приложения, к которой у негоесть доступ, в нее можно генерить файлы из приложения. Если нужно из исходников на телефон, то assets или raw в ресурсах. Как доставать гуглите, ищется довольно легко

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ну мне только для чтения. Как считать?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Создайте папку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18302624/3212712) `assets` по пути `проект/app/src/main`
2. Поместите в неё файл.
3. Считайте его в строку [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16110044/3212712)

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
InputStream json = getAssets().open("имяФайла.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(json, "UTF-8"));
String str;

while ((str=in.readLine()) != null) {
  buf.append(str);
}

in.close();
```

Comment: Мне нужен InputStream для Scanner

Comment: @Евгений, я не понимаю к чему вы клоните.

Comment: у меня есть готовый метод для работы с специально заготовленным TXT файлом, надо InputStream файла получить.

Comment: Значит просто одну строку оставьте: `InputStream in = getAssets().open("имяФайла.txt")`

Comment: Это не работает. Может ли быть дело в том, что я исполняю этот InputStream в другом классе?

Comment: @Евгений, "не работает" можно расшифровать несколькими способами. Ошибка компиляции или времени исполнения. Последняя может быть нескольких видов, вызываться по нескольким причинам. Описание всех возможных причин и их исправления не поместится в ответ.